# How can I improve the look of my footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, footer

Do you maybe have any tips on what to do with footnotes in order to make them look better or more readable?

[image: IA]

Comment: Some radical suggestions are either to eliminate footnotes or to use _margin notes_ instead. The Tufte-LaTeX class does some nifty preparation for that, but it has some problems with many margin notes on a single page. In short, there are two kinds of them, floating and not, both with some deficits.

Comment: You should probably start before LaTeX even comes into play: How would you like your footnotes to be different? What are you looking for? “Just make them prettier” is not too useful and very much open to debate anyway. That said, I would perhaps try a non-serif font, smaller font size (compared to the text), reduced line spacing, and think about indenting the second and following lines of a note. (See how “Harvard” sticks out to the left in your first footnote?)

Comment: The main point of the footnotes is to allow access to details of doubtful importance without distract to the reader of the important information. Liking first Oleg's idea at this respect some people say that if a footnote is important should be included in the main text, and otherwise should not be in manuscript at all. Anyway, is a design-style problem with subjective opinion-based solutions that are not specific of TeX, so off-topic here.

Comment: You could use endnotes and put all the footnotes at the end of the chapter.